Spring Boot (2.7) webapp on Tomcat 9, no logging from any Controller exception or slf4 Logger statement
I am deploying a spring boot (2.7) war to tomcat (9.0.47) the logging work ok, except if it is from a controller method, from controller methods no 404, 500 or LOGGER.warn statement are logged at all, neither template not found or thymeleaf compilation errors are logged, making it very difficult to debug the app. How do i fix the LOGGING.
logback.xml
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -%kvp- %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.appname" level="fine"
            additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>

Logging in build.gradle
         implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.12'
         implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.12'
         implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.7.18'
         implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.5.12'
         implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version: '2.0.16'


Is there any reason, why you are upgrading logback & slf4j versions?
